# Reduce margins in GGPlot, having problems with plot.margin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my plot to fill more of the screen-much of it is dominated by white space and it is difficult to see the actual plot. I've tried plot.margin=margin and plot.margin=unit with no success.  I must be doing something slightly wrong. I appreciate any advice on decreasing white space and increasing the plot itself.

[image: Image I'm trying to alter]

Here is a subset of my code

```
Date          Location       Temperature
1/1/2013      Effluent       47
1/2/2013      Effluent       47
1/3/2013      Effluent       47
1/4/2013      Effluent       47
1/1/2013      BDT            56
1/2/2013      BDT            57
1/3/2013      BDT            60
1/4/2013      BDT            56

temp<-read.csv("temperature.csv", header=TRUE)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)
ggplot(temp, aes(x = mdy(Date), y = Temperature, color = Location)) +
  geom_point(size = .5) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5))) +
  coord_fixed(12) +
  ylab("Temperature (\u00B0F)") +
  scale_x_date(name = "", breaks = date_breaks("1 year"), labels = date_format("%b %Y")) + 
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Effluent", "RSW-002", "RSW-002A", "RRI", "SJG", "BDT"),
                       breaks = c("Effluent", "RSW-002", "RSW-002A", "RRI", "SJG", "BDT")) + scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=16, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0, size=16), axis.text.y = element_text(size=16), axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=3, size=16, face="bold"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.margin=margin(c(0,0,0,0,"cm"))) 
ggsave("TEMP.png", width=15, height = 8, dpi = 300)
```

Comment: You seem to force a fixed ratio with `coord_fixed(12)`, and an aspect ratio of the png, giving both height and width. Maybe you fixing just one dimension in the png might help.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main thing to point out is that this has nothing to do with whitespace as such. You're asking for `coord_fixed`, so ggplot will take up the maximum space it can on the x-axis, while obeying your command to keep the ratio of y axis:x axis constant. With the ratio you have specified, it simply has nothing to draw near the top or bottom of the plot, and will only do so if you specify a higher ratio.

One other thing I've changed: the `margin()` function takes its arguments directly without the `c()`.

I've had to make up some data to get my plot into approximately the same shape as yours.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)

temp <- data.frame(
          Date = as.Date(rep(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01") + days(1:2590), 6)),
          Temperature = (sin(2*pi* 1:15540/365.25) + 1) * 20 + 40 + rnorm(15540, 0, 3),
          Location = rep(c("Effluent","RSW-002","RSW-002A","RRI","SJG","BDT"), each = 2590))

ggplot(temp, aes(x = Date, y = Temperature, color = Location)) +
geom_point(size = .5) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) + 
  coord_fixed(20) +
  ylab("Temperature (\u00B0F)") +
  scale_x_date(name = "", 
               breaks = date_breaks("1 year"), 
               labels = date_format("%b %Y")) + 
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Effluent", "RSW-002", "RSW-002A", "RRI", "SJG", "BDT"),
                       breaks = c("Effluent", "RSW-002", "RSW-002A", "RRI", "SJG", "BDT")) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0, size = 16), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=16), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=3, size=16, face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, "cm"))

ggsave("TEMP.png", width = 15, height = 8, dpi = 300)
```

And TEMP.png looks like this:

[image]